# gnome-terminal keeps the menubar even when the profile is configured to hide it

Tags: 11.10, gnome-terminal

I am running gnome classic on 11.10 and even though I have configured the gnome-terminal profile to hide the menu bar it shows it.

Even when I open the `gnome-terminal --hide-menubar` it shows the menu bar.

Any idea how to resolve that?

I even used gconf-editor to see if there is a problem with the profile but it has the parameter to show the menubar by default in false.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but you could always use xterm if you don't like the menu.

Comment: thanks @bntser but I really like gnome-terminal, and if I were to use another terminal I'd use roxterm or eterm :)

Comment: This is very annoying. I found a bug report for this issue here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/875070

Comment: I even used gconf-editor to see if there is a problem with the profile but it has the parameter to show the menubar by default in false.may be i can help you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my case it was related to [Eliminate the top "mac-ish" file/edit/view/... menu after installing gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68166/eliminate-the-top-mac-ish-file-edit-view-menu-after-installing-gnome)

When I moved my top bar away with `Alt + Right click` (for example to the right side of the screen) an extra menubar showed up on the top of the screen. It was probably hidden under the top bar I moved away.

After running `sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt` and a reboot `gnome-terminal --hide-menubar` worked again :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's been hacking me off since I upgrade to gnome 3.

Comment: Just confirm it worked in cairo-dock session with gnome-panel loaded  manually (from gnome-session-fallback) which doesn't have a  menubar.

Comment: Excellent! Works on 11.10!